# How to css transition different img

Tags: css, image, transition

I have a img  in html

I want to show 3 different img in a 4 second time lapse in css code.

PD:i found this example, but i don't understant it.
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to help when you have not tried anything yourself.

Comment: well your example is ok... just start with some basic.

Comment: Sorry you don't understand the example, but that's not exactly a question.  Typically when you click "Ask Question" on StackOverflow, it's customary to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, using CSS only.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="img></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#img {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    -webkit-animation:changeBG 12s ease infinite;
    -ms-animation:changeBG 12s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation:changeBG 12s ease infinite;
    -o-animation:changeBG 12s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeBG {
    0% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f20808/fff'); }
    50% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000'); }
    100% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff'); }
}
@-moz-keyframes changeBG {
    0% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f20808/fff'); }
    50% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000'); }
    100% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff'); }
}
@-ms-keyframes changeBG {
    0% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f20808/fff'); }
    50% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000'); }
    100% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff'); }
}
@-o-keyframes changeBG {
    0% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f20808/fff'); }
    50% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000'); }
    100% { background:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff'); }
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/4XaX4/)**

Comment: Thx alot karim, it forks fine and looks pretty easy.


Here is my example: http://gotomusic.2trweb.com/privat.html .


I put this for work in firefox, but dont work, only on chrome. 
    -webkit-animation:changeBG 20s  infinite;
    -moz-animation: changeBG 20s  infinite;
    -o-animation:   changeBG 20s  infinite;
    animation:  changeBG 20s  infinite;

Comment: @QuimSerra I edited my answer to work on all browsers

Comment: jajaj OK :D. Thats cool, ty men !   pd: i cant vote positive, i need 15 reputation :'(

Comment: and now you've got 17 :D hehehehe

Comment: still not work [
http://gotomusic.2trweb.com/privat.html ].

Comment: well, if i put a background in #img_privat_keyframe, now the image dont change :S